# What is the syntax of a query WHERE value1 or value2 is IN (x, y, z)?

Tags: mysql, database

The syntax for a `WHERE` statement using `IN` is:

```
SELECT ... WHERE value IN (x, y, z)
```

I would like to do:

```
SELECT ... WHERE value1 or value2 IN (x, y, z)
```

The reason why I cannot do:

```
SELECT ... WHERE value1 IN (x, y, z) OR value2 IN (x, y, z)
```

is because `(x, y, z)` comes from another nested `SELECT` query and I have to believe that calling it twice is not a good practice (I may be wrong). What is the best method to accomplish this without having 2 nested queries like:

```
SELECT ... WHERE value1 IN ( SELECT same... ) OR value2 IN ( SELECT same... )
```

?

EDIT: An example of the nested query could be:

```
SELECT idx FROM table1 WHERE type = 'typeA' LIMIT 3000
```

which may give 3000 rows, and I don't think calling it twice as a nested query is wise.

Comment: Add nested query as well

Comment: @JaydipJ What do you mean? Can you give me an example?

Comment: I mean what kind of nested query in where clause, add sample nested query in your question so that others can help you

Comment: @JaydipJ Ah ok ok. I will do. Thank you for the reminder! I do think a general case would be great because it is the results of the same query.

Comment: Your sub-query should probably be a join, and the OR should probably be a UNION. Along the lines of `SELECT * FROM Table0 t0 JOIN Table1 t1 ON t0.value1 = t1.idx AND t1.type = 'typeA' UNION SELECT * FROM Table0 t0 JOIN Table1 t1 ON t0.value2 = t1.idx AND t1.type = 'typeA'`.  However, UNION comes with its own set of foibles (it eliminates duplicates) which may or may not be what you want.  And it isn't entirely clear how well this will perform.  It depends in part on the size of tables, and the indexing schemes, and the general inventiveness of the optimizer in handling queries well.

Comment: Thank you for your input @JonathanLeffler! I think you answer the question itself, but in my case (which i havent specifically stated), I have a `LIMIT 30` on the subquery. Then i check if value1 or value2 are in those results. I think the `LIMIT 30` is what makes it impossible to mix those statements into 2 subqueries.

Comment: What does the LIMIT 30 mean?  And the LIMIT 3000 which is lurking in the question?  It could mean that you miss matches that would otherwise occur.  It probably makes your query non-deterministic.  I'm not convinced that it's a good idea, whatever it does to your query.  You're now fighting the internals of MySQL, rather than working within the remit of the SQL standard — LIMIT is not a part of standard SQL, at least not AFAIK.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes you are right, it isn't very deterministic. The sql is more like 2 queries, where 1 gets enough data with LIMIT 3000, and another that gets all the rest of the data depending on what is fetched from the first query. I have decided to just separate it into two queries instead, for now. In any case thank you for your time! :)